# Force adding slach to the end in RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, s3-rewrite-rules

i'm working with mod_rewrite under .htaccess, and i'm trying to fore adding a slach "/" to the end of the url : 
interpret this url : `http://domain/ABC/DEF` like this `http://domain/ABC/DEF/`

how can i write the rule please ?

Answer (score 1):

To add a trailing slash at the end of Request_uri, You can use the following rule in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
#If there is already a trailing slash, skip the rule.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
#else redirect any request to add a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

This automatically adds a trailing slash and changes the url

- http://example.com/foo/bar

to

- http://example.com/foo/bar/

The RewriteCond is important here to avoid **redirect loop**  error, without this condition a request for /foo redirects to /foo/ on initial iteration, On the second iteration the target url /foo/ matches the Rewrite pattern and redirects /foo/ to /foo/ and causes the loop error.

(Hope ,This helps!)